# struct not returning first row

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to figure out why I'm missing the first row of a 2D array contained in my struct. I printed the first value of the first row prior to leaving the previous function, which assigns values to the 2D array. In the next function that is called, which will act based on the values in the array, I printed the value again to see if they match, but they don't.  The value that is printed is the first value of the second row. Printing the rest of the 2D array shows that I'm missing the entire first row, even though the last print statement prior to executing this function displayed that the first row is there.  There is no other statements between the last print statement and this print statement, other than calling the function.

```
filename.csv
ProcessID,AT,BT,Priority
2,0,5,4
3,0,3,2 
1,9,8,1
4,4,6,3
...

typedef struct _Scheduler {
    int processes[10][4];
    ...
} Scheduler;

void readfile(char *file) {
    Scheduler data;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    // ignore first line
    // add integers to 2D array
    ....
    ....
    fclose(fp);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
             printf("%d,", data.processes[i][j]);
        }
        ...
        printf("\n");
    } 
    // prints 
    // 2,0,5,4
    // 3,0,3,2
    // 1,9,8,1
    // 4,4,6,3
}

void FCFS() {
    Scheduler data;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
             printf("%d,", data.processes[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
    // prints 
    // 3,0,3,2 
    // 1,9,8,1
    // 4,4,6,3
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    readfile(argv[1]);
    FCFS();
    ...
}
```

I expect data.processes[0][0] in FCFS() to print 2, but it prints 3. Printing the rest of the values show that its missing the first row, even though at the end of the last function, it prints all 4 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void FCFS() {
    Scheduler data;
    printf("Retrieved value: %d\n", data.processes[0][0]); 
    // prints 3
    ...
}
```

This creates a *local* copy of the structure that will bear no relationship to what was read in by `readfile()` into *its* local copy. It will most likely contain arbitrary data.

I suspect the only reason it would have the actual data (offset by one row) is that `readfile()` had *other* local variables in there that put its `Scheduler` variable at a different address on the stack.

Then, when calling `FCFS()`, the arbitrary data that it uses is the data left there in the stachk area by `readfile()` (slightly offset as previously mentioned).

You could check this by printing out `&data` in both those functions to see if they are offset slightly.

To fix this, you need to make a *single* `data` variable that's shared somehow by the two functions. The easiest way would be to make a file-level global, instantiating it outside of the functions like:

```
static Scheduler data;

void readfile(char *file) {
    ....
    ....
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Value assigned: %d\n", data.processes[0][0]); 
    // prints 2
}

void FCFS() {
    printf("Retrieved value: %d\n", data.processes[0][0]); 
    // prints 3
    ...
}
```

There are *other* options (which would be better than globals in a non-trivial program) but you can probably get away with a global for now.

Comment: ... and there is the confirmation by OP.

Comment: So, how do I call the data in the struct without re-declaring data.  If I remove the first line, shows data.processes unresolved.

Comment: @N.Colostate, I've added a bit to show one way to do that.

Comment: @Yunnosch, admittedly, the original question had `data` as a local within `FCFS()` so I *knew* it was different. The rest was just educated supposition as to what would cause the off-by-N behaviour rather than totally random content.

Comment: @N.Colostate I think you might have been told by somebody recently, not to use a global variable for this. Just a hunch, because the code looks like it comes from having a global. Please comment.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I'm no JonSkeet but I do okay :-)